# YouTube API: Show channel name - Error message

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, channel

We are programming a webapp with the YouTube API (in PHP).
We already programmed a site where you can connect your YouTube channel.

On the next site we want to show the name and the uploads from the connected channel.
For this we used the following code:

```
  $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId by $channel['snippet']['title']</h3><ul>";
  foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
      $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
  }
  $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
```

The uploads function is working, but the name function isn't.
If we go on the site with the browser we get the following error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in .../dashboard.php on line 53

On line 53 is this code:

```
  $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId by $channel['snippet']['title']</h3><ul>";
```

The definition of $channel we already set.

What's the mistake?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use an array value with a quoted key inside a double-quoted string.

The proper way to do this is by wrapping variables in curly braces `{ }`:

```
$htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list {$uploadsListId} by 
{$channel['snippet']['title']}</h3><ul>";
```

Or concatenate them:

```
$htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list " . $uploadsListId . " by 
" . $channel['snippet']['title'] . "</h3><ul>";
```

Or, use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) (looks more neater in my opinion):

```
$htmlBody .= sprintf('<h3>Videos in list %d by %s',
$uploadsListId, $channel['snippet']['title'] );
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I changed the code, now the error message is away. On the site I see the uploads but the channel name isn't there. It would be great if you can help me via. teamviewer or I can send you the files.